# SQL Select based on Link Field

Tags: sql, select, join

I feel like an idiot asking this...

```
Table 1: users
id serial
person integer
username char(32)

Table 2:persons
id serial
name char(16)
```

Can I run a query that returns the name field in persons by providing the username in users?

```
users
1 | 1 | larry123

persons
1 | larry
2 | curly
```

SQL?

```
select name from persons where users.person=persons.id and users.username='larry123';
```

with the desired return of

```
larry
```

I have been doing it with two passes until now and think maybe a nested select using a join is what I need

```
1 | larry
```

Comment: There are no stupid questions! However , could you please frame the question so that it becomes more clear?

Answer (score 5):

It *sounds* like you're asking how to do a join in SQL:

```
SELECT
    name
  FROM
    users JOIN persons ON (users.person = persons.id)
  WHERE
    users.username = 'larry123';
```

that is almost the query you wrote. All you were missing was the join clause. You could also do that join like this:

```
SELECT name
FROM users, persons
WHERE
      users.person = persons.id
  AND users.username = 'larry123';
```

I suggest finding a well-written introduction to SQL.